# iPhone - NSURLConnection async upload file failed with wifi for ios6

Tags: iphone, wifi, nsurlconnection

I have implemented my `NSURLConnection` method to upload file to my server, everything works perfectly fine until the device is upgraded to iOS6. Now, it works fine under 3G, but when connecting via wifi, the uploading just stops half way and hang there till the timeout sets in.

After some examination, using wifi:

1. when uploading a smaller file, `didSendBodyData` delegate will be called multiple times, which is fine, but the weird thing is that after `totalBytesWritten` is equivalent to `totalBytesExpectedToWrite`, it will pause for awhile, and the same delegate will be called again, and now, `totalBytesExpectedToWrite` will become 2x of the original file size.
2. when uploading a larger file, `didSendBodyData` delegate will be called multiple times, but `totalBytesWritten` will never reach `totalBytesExpectedToWrite`. It will stop halfway, and the delegate will not be called again till timeout.

Below is a brief how I initiate the sending of file:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:MyURI];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setTimeoutInterval:600];
[req setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData];
[req setValue:@"application/octet-stream" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req setValue:userName forHTTPHeaderField:@"AuthField1"];
[req setValue:authorizationToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"AuthField2"];

[req setHTTPBody:data];

NSURLConnection *reqConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

What is the change for connecting via wifi in iOS6? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if Charles Proxy will give any insight:  http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/